# Displaying popup images on button click

Tags: android, android-widget

Please refer the image given in the url
http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0AQhgDtGvE2HgZGZ6cmtua185M2RneG5nYmNm&hl=en

My query is, How can I display the messages corresponding to the rounded buttons and the table row , when I click on the rounded button with question mark.

I know, I have to use listener for the ? button , but what should I do in listener exactly, such that when I click, it shows those alerts(images) and when I click again, it disappears.

For this UI, I have used Relative layout as was suggested here -- [Aligning components at desired positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544988/aligning-components-at-desired-positions) -- and it worked perfect for me.

So, do I need to change my base layout altogether for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `FrameLayout` as the base for your ui layout and then add an `ImageView` overlay.  For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Put your normal layout stuff here -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your code you can create the `ImageView` and add it to the `MainFrame` and it will overlay your UI, like this:

```
FrameLayout mainFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainFrame);
ImageView overlay = new ImageView(this);
overlay.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.overlay));
mainFrame.addView(overlay);
```

Then later you can call:

```
mainFrame.removeView(overlay);
```

to have it go away.

Comment: used ur way but i got  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first...